# Wait for 10 seconds while download file being generated - Why they create and where to get those codes?

Tags: wordpress

I noticed so many Downloads websites create those download links. Eg: Go to any post and Try to download the product, you will get a redirect to another page before they show you too real download links.

https://null-24.com
http://thewpclub.net/

The purpose they might be doing to reduce traffic Bounce rates... not very sure. Can anybody of you help me to understand this and provide any help to get those codes? They might be wordpress plugin or custom codes.. not very sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 percent sure if you aking this, but...

They do it this way because they do not want another site to parse their links.

Another possibility is if the content is paid - they prevent you to send the links to hundred of your friends.

Lastly, if you pay for streaming, and suppose you have 24h right for streaming, they will invalidate your link after that.

If you ask how this can be done, there are several possibilities.

If content is small, say phone ringtone, you can copy it in download directory, then delete itafter some time.

If content is big and you are on Linux, you can do symlink or hardlink, then delete it.

You can also do it via PHP, Java or whatever technology you are using, but it is far away from the best way. not recommended at all.

Finally, you can use server like nginx or apache. Both of them have modules for this kind of expiring links. Then you can have your website on one of the servers and download will be made from totaly separated server, aven located at different datacenter.  The remote server will not need any programs running there, except apache or nginx. This is the only realistic way for streaming large content (movies, music, 3D, games) over the internet.